# SwiftUI Animation Bindings

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var animationAmount = 1.0
    var body: some View {
        VStack
        {
            Stepper("Scale amount", value: $animationAmount.animation(.linear), in: 1...10)
            
            
            
            Spacer()
            Button("Tap Me")
            {
                animationAmount += 1
            }
            .padding(50)
            .background(.red)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .scaleEffect(animationAmount)
           
        }
    }
}
```

So I have a tiny question, here I made a Stepper view with value being some way two binding of a variable and then I called the .animation method on that binding which from what I understood, if any changes happen to that binding they simply get animated.
My question is, is it specifically only changes that relate to the binding value that get animated? Or if some other changes happen to this view but coincidentally they happened a bit before the binding changed would those changes get animated too?

And another super super tiny question, why is it exactly that I can't put an if statement in this VStack that will increment animationAmount?
like

```
if animationAmount > 1.0
{
   animationAmount += 0.25
}
```

Just says that () doesn't conform to View.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62098097/12299030 for details on how binding.animation works and why it is needed.

Comment: This is said in the post "Animation to Binding is a mechanism to transfer animation inside child so when bound variable is changed internally it would be changed with animation" so from what I understand from this the binding animation will only animate views that get changed as a result of the binding and even if I change something about the view with some different variable it won't get animated because it isn't because of the binding, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, `.animation(_:value:)`:

> Applies the given animation to this view when the specified value changes.

So yes, the animation applies only when the value you passed changes, see more: [.animation(_:value:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/path/animation(_:value:))

To answer your second question,`VStack, HStack,... & body` are `ViewBuilders`. Meaning they require you to pass in a `View`, whereas `animationAmount += 0.25` is of type `Void` != `View`. So what you should do is use `.onChange`:

```
.onChange(of: animationAmount) { newValue in
    if animationAmount > 1.0 {
        animationAmount += 0.25
    }
}
```

Comment: Still kinda unsure about the first part though because I did some testing and it seems .animation will just animate something after a particular value changes but even if there is some unrelated value there that also somehow changed and changes something in the views then what it did also gets animated. Not sure if I explained that correctly but basically .animation just looks for one value to change and if it changes, it animations every View that changed as a result of that but if there is another value that changed same time and changed the views those changes also get animated

Comment: My question is, is it the same case with the animation method on binding? If some change happens to the binding but there are also some other changes to the view will those get animated as well or will only the views that change due to the binding change get animated?

Comment: Yes it is the same on bindings, & other changes will also get animated.

Answer (score 0):

First question: **.animation** works by animating a specific component whenever the value of this component changes.

eg: **foregroundColor(color.animation)** meaning that if the value of variable **color** changes, animation will happen BUT only to this **foregroundColor** component, unless you give another component **color.animation** too. Any other changes in view/variable beside this variable **color** will not apply animation to this **foregroundColor**. Any change even a very small change of variable **color** will animate the **foregroundColor**.

There is another different type of animation called **withAnimation**.

eg: **withAnimation { isViewed = true }**, now all the views or modifiers that relate to this variable **isViewed** will be animated.

Second question: To make it easy to understand, you simply can’t make any calculation/logic process inside a **SwiftUI View Bracket**. An **ifelse{} statement** inside a **VStack** or **var body** expects **Views**, so you can’t make any calculation there because it is not a view. Any code inside this ifelse bracket **{. . .}** shall be views only.

However, an **ifelse{} statement** inside a **Button Action** or **onTapGesture** is an opposite story. You can make any calculation/logic process there except displaying views. To understand formally about these concepts you should explore more about the basic of SwiftUI.